# Castle-Windsor Fluent Interface: How to register all implementations of all interfaces?

Tags: .net, castle-windsor, fluent-interface

I have two assemblies **EDC2.DAL** and **EDC2** where EDC2.DaoInterfaces defines a bunch of interfaces for data access objects to objects in the EDC2.Domain namespace.  These are all implemented by classes in EDC2.DAL.

So to give an example:

```
Assembly EDC2
  Namespace EDC2.DaoInterfaces
    ICustomerDao
    IProductDao
Assembly EDC2.DAL
  Namespace EDC2.DAL
    CustomerDao : ICustomerDao
    ProductDao : IProductDao
```

I would like to use Windsor's fluent interface to register all interfaces in EDC2.DaoInterfaces as being implemented by their corresponding implementors in EDC2.DAL.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Castle Windsor: Auto-register types from one assembly that implement interfaces from another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070375/castle-windsor-auto-register-types-from-one-assembly-that-implement-interfaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution [here](http://blogger.forgottenskies.com/?p=266):

```
AllTypes.Pick().FromAssemblyNamed("EDC2.DAL").If(x => !x.IsGenericType).WithService.FirstInterface()
```