# Castle Windsor: Auto-register types from one assembly that implement interfaces from another

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container, fluent-interface

I use [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/) as my [IoC container](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).  I have an application that has a structure similar to the following:

- MyApp.Services.dll

  - `IEmployeeService`
  - `IContractHoursService`
  - `...`
- MyApp.ServicesImpl.dll

  - `EmployeeService : MyApp.Services.IEmployeeService`
  - `ContractHoursService : MyApp.Services.IContractHoursService`
  - `...`

I use the [XML configuration](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v21/usersguide/externalconfig.html) at the moment, and every time I add a new IService/Service pair, I have to add a new component to the XML configuration file.  I want to switch all this over to the [fluent registration API](http://using.castleproject.org/display/IoC/Fluent+Registration+API) but haven't worked out *exactly* the right recipe to do what I want yet.

Can anyone help?  The lifestyles will all be `singleton`.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `AllTypes` you can easily do this:

From http://stw.castleproject.org/(S(nppam045y0sdncmbazr1ob55))/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx:

> Registering components one-by-one can be very repetitive job. Also remembering to register each new type you add can quickly lead to frustration. Fortunately, you don't have to do it, at least always. By using AllTypes entry class you can perform group registration of types based on some specified characteristics you specify.

I think your registration would look like:

```
AllTypes.FromAssembly(typeof(EmployeeService).Assembly)
    .BasedOn<IEmployeeService>()
    .LifeStyle.Singleton
```

If you implement a base type, like `IService` on your interfaces, you can register them all at once using the following construct:

```
AllTypes.FromAssembly(typeof(EmployeeService).Assembly)
    .BasedOn<IService>()
    .WithService.FromInterface()
    .LifeStyle.Singleton
```

For more examples, see the article. This has a very good description on what the possibilities are.

Comment: This doesn't do 100% what I need, though.  There are different service interfaces in the first assembly, and I have a one-one mapping with a concrete instance.  I'd have to write the above code over and over again as I do for the xml config now.

Comment: Is it an option to have a base interface for `IEmployeeService`? That's what I did. You can tell Windsor to look for that interface, register everything below it (so, specifically `IEmployeeService`) with the implementations from the assembly. Expanded the answer with an example.

Comment: You mean like having a simple `IService` with no members that acts as a marker interface?  That could work, I was just hoping I could avoid it. :)

Comment: How would you otherwise be able to find your types? It's a very common solution.

Comment: @Neil: use reflection to iterate over the interfaces in MyApp.Services.dll

Comment: @Mauricio Turns out that's not necessary - there's a `WithService.FirstInterface()` method I can use - I've posted my answer below.

Comment: As of Windsor 3, using [`AllTypes` is discouraged](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx)

Answer (score 5):

I took [Pieter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070375/castle-windsor-auto-register-types-from-one-assembly-that-implement-interfaces-f/4070403#4070403) forward just a little bit (the key being, as he suggested, `AllTypes`) and have come up with this:

```
// Windsor 2.x
container.Register(
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyApp.ServicesImpl")
    .Where(type => type.IsPublic)
    .WithService.FirstInterface()
    );
```

This goes through all public classes in the `MyApp.ServicesImpl.dll` assembly and registers each in the container using the first interface it implements.  Because I want all the classes in the services assembly, I need no marker interface.

The above works for an old version of Windsor.  The current [Castle Windsor documentation for registering components](http://stw.castleproject.org/(S(nppam045y0sdncmbazr1ob55))/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx) for the latest version suggests the following:

```
// Windsor latest
container.Register(
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("MyApp.ServicesImpl")
    .Where(type => type.IsPublic) // Filtering on public isn't really necessary (see comments) but you could put additional filtering here
    .WithService.DefaultInterface()
    );
```

Comment: you don't need `Where(type => type.IsPublic)`. Windsor will only scan exported types (which means public or nested public) by default anyway.

Comment: I thought that, but I think you need `Where(something)` though because the `WithService` method isn't on the return value of `FromAssemblyNamed()`.  Oh, unless I had an #intellisensefail... I'll check...

Comment: I've just checked, it definitely doesn't compile for me.  Since I'm currently on an older version of Windsor, I'll assume it's down to that, and update the answer above regarding Windsor latest.  Thanks very much for the input. :)