# How to register all assemblies with implementations of all interfaces from another assembly in Castle Windsor?

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

Is it possible to pass to Castle name of the assembly that contains all our interfaces, and have Castle automatically find and register all assemblies in the current directory that contain implementations of those interfaces?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070375/castle-windsor-auto-register-types-from-one-assembly-that-implement-interfaces?

Comment: @Marijn indeed, looks like it :) I'll have a better look once I'm in front of a computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code solved the problem for me. Please comment if you see any problems with it.

```
var InterfacesAssemblyName = /* get assembly name from appSettings */;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(InterfacesAssemblyName))
{
    var interfaces = Assembly.Load(InterfacesAssemblyName).GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsInterface && type.IsPublic).ToList();

    this._container.Register(
        Classes
            .FromAssemblyInDirectory(new AssemblyFilter("bin"))
            .Where(x => x.GetInterfaces().Intersect(interfaces).Any())
            .LifestyleTransient()
            .WithService.DefaultInterfaces());
}
```

Comment: Actually, this only matches implementations that have similar names (ie DefaultInterfaces). Which is not exactly what the question asked?