# "Reverse-Resolution" with an Ioc Container?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container

Instead of registering an interface-to-class binding, I want to register a class and have the IOC container implicitly register the interface(s) associated with that class.  I'd like to know if any IOC container can do this, though I specifically need the answer for Unity.

To make clear what I'm after, notice:

```
public interface IFred
{
    int Go();
}
public class Fred : IFred
{
    public int Go()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<Fred>();     //contra-variant registration?
        IFred foo = container.Resolve<IFred>();  //variant resolution?
    }
}
```

In the above example,  I want a "Fred" instance returned, even though I did not explicitly register an IFred mapping.

Comment: +1 for "contra-variant registration", hehe :) ... What happens if `Fred` implements `IFred`, `IDisposable`, and `IEquatable<IFred>`?

Comment: @Jeff: Presumably the IOC container operates on default rules, such as "succeed if there is exactly one interface" or user-defined rules such as "pick the interface that matches a given namespace pattern."

Comment: Gotcha, I didn't know if you were thinking about writing a convenience/wrapper method around Unity or something.

Comment: Did you explicitly *not* implement `IFred` on `Fred`? There will be no container that would automatically allow you to guess interfaces for you. There are containers on the other hand that allow you to register types based on convensions. Castle Windows for instance allow you to register 'all classes from an assembly with as service the first interface' ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4076221/264697)). What the 'first interface' is however, is undefined. So you rather not implement more than one interface.

Comment: @Steven: My bad.  Can't believe I didn't notice that bug.  Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I know of a couple (not **Unity** though sorry)

Autofac:

```
ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder
    .RegisterType<Fred>()
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

and Castle Windsor:

```
WindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(
    Classes
        .From(typeof(Fred))
        .Pick()
        .LifestyleTransient()
        .WithServiceAllInterfaces());
```

Comment: There does appear to be built-in support for this in Unity 3: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/agile/archive/2013/03/12/unity-configuration-registration-by-convention.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.withmappings.fromallinterfaces(v=pandp.30).aspx.